# How do I install Chocolatey packages offline?

Tags: chocolatey

I am trying to automate to set up a developer machine software installation. Chocolatey is good to install packages when you connected to the Internet. Is there a way to install packages offline?

I just want to put all the packages in a shared network folder and use that packages to install. If you have an internal application, how do you convert them into a Chocolatey package?

Answer (score 10):

#### Caching Downloads - Not Deterministic

While there are ways to set the original nupkg (with the version on it, not the one in the packages directory - use download from left side of packages page on the [Chocolatey community package repository](http://chocolatey.org/packages)) and preset the downloaded binaries into the cache folder, it's not always deterministic that it will work. You can also override the cache location, so that the folder is somewhere not in TEMP. See `choco config`, `choco config -h` and `choco config set cacheLocation c:\some\location` to do this.

#### Create Your Own Packages - Better

For packages you need offline, you have the ability to manage your own packages and you can embed software right into the package. This is desired when you want to manage software offline as most things on the community repository are subject to copyright law and distribution rights (why they don't simply have the software they represent embedded).

Creating and working with your own packages is very secure, but it does tend to take up time. If you are doing this for yourself, then it could override any time-savings you get as a consumer using Chocolatey and the community repository.

For organizations, we've developed Package Builder, which creates full software deployments (packages) in 5-10 seconds. It can also create packages right out of existing installed software (Programs and Features) in under 60 seconds! Read more about [Package Builder](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-create-packages-from-installers).

#### Internalized Packages - Best

The best thing you can do here is a process called internalizing, where you download and extract the package, download all of the resources and embed them in the package (or put them somewhere local), edit the scripts to use those embedded/local resources and recompile the package.

This allows you to take advantage of existing package logic without the issue of the internet.

For more details see [Manually Internalizing Packages](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-recompile-packages) and [Package Internalizer - Automatically Internalize Packages](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-automatically-recompile-packages).

#### Organization Use of Chocolatey

Most organizations using Chocolatey are doing some combination of creating packages and internalizing packages, because they need reliability and absolute trust and control over those packages when being used in production scenarios.

Comment: The good thread : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/chocolatey/stHHzK-mzMY/32h7T9wlHKAJ

Answer (score 5):

I've created a project named ChocolateStore that automates the process of copying a Chocolatey package from an online source and making the package available for offline use.

You can view the source here: 
https://github.com/BahKoo/ChocolateStore

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey’s documentation may answer the first part of the question with this: "[How To Host Your Own [Private/Internal/Public] Package Repository Server (aka Package Feed)](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed)"

It explains three types of package repositories which enable you to provide packages in your LAN/intranet or through shared volumes:

1. [Folder/UNC share](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed#local-folder--unc-share)
2. [Simple server](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed#simple-server)
3. [Package gallery](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed#package-gallery)

The second part of the question could be answered with [Chocolatey’s documentation about recompiling packages](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-recompile-packages). The title sounds more complicated than it really is and could just have been "How to make an existing package local", and I think what is described there can be applied to what the question’s author calls "internal applications" (I guess he means programs aka .exe files which are not available on any public feed), too.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have created a [Nullsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft) installer that needed to install Chocolatey packages from an offline computer.  These are the overall steps:

1. Download the Chocolatey packages to a temporary directory with:

   ```
   NuGet.exe Install some_package_name -OutputDirectory C:\Temp\ChocoPackages -ExcludeVersion
   ```
2. In the Nullsoft script, add these lines to pick up the download packages:

   ```
   nsExec::Exec 'choco feature disable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation'
   ```

   SetOutPath "${TmpPath}ChocoPackages"
   File /r "C:\Temp\ChocoPackages*.*"
3. While still in the Nullsoft script, use this command to install a Chocolatey package from the temporary directory that the files were placed at during the install process:

   ```
   choco install --Source "${TmpPath}ChocoPackages" ${Name_Of_ChocoPackage} --acceptlicense --yes
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Nifty. That's exactly what I'm doing currently!

For what it's worth, to install from a network shared folder, I'm using:

```
choco upgrade eclipse -y -s \\network\users\KyleStoflet\Eclipse
```

For example, here I'm upgrading Eclipse, and I'll explain the line a bit more:

`-y` skips the confirmation

`-s` provides the source path

`network` and `users` are placeholders for our network, and user directories

... and for *test purposes*, I've got our versions in my directory. Inside that directory there are multiple directories for Eclipse, Visual Studio, and other various software that we use for development.

**An important note:** I've only gotten this working for the .nupkg files that were retrieved directly from the [Chocolatey packages page](https://chocolatey.org/packages). I didn't end up finding a fix for executables.

Answer (score 0):

Put the installer in the cache directory:

```
%TEMP%\chocolatey\<pkg>\<version>
```

And do a force install:

```
choco install -f <package_name>
```

It worked fine on my version (v0.9.10.3).

Comment: Of course you can override the cache location - see `choco config` and `choco config set cacheLocation c:\somewhere`

Answer (score 0):

Chocolatey uses `$env:TEMP` as a cache directory and the download file put at

```
$env:Temp\chocolatey\Firefox\60.0.2\FirefoxInstall.exe
```

60.0.2 is the package version, and Firefox is the package name.

Answer (score 0):

**A.How to install chocolatey package offline with chocolatey**

1. Download the chocolatey NuPackage from chocolatey website. https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey
2. Put it in a local file repository, example: `D:\chocoOfflineRepository`
3. `choco source add -n=chocoOfflineControl -s="file:///d:/chocoOfflineRepository/"`
4. `choco install -f package`

*Optional:*
In my case, I also set the cache folder to my external D drive, instead of a Temp folder on my admin user account.

5. `choco config set cacheLocation D:\chocoOfflineRepository`

**B. How to install chocolatey offline**

Also, assuming your already have chocolatey installed, But, just in case

1. Read this:
   https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#completely-offline-install
2. Download chocolatey Nupackage file and put in local file repository
3. Copy suggested .ps1 scripts.
4. Modify package url source for local source

```
$packageRepo = 'file:///d:/chocoOfflineRepository/chocolatey.0.10.15.nupkg'
```

5. Modify search url for simpler

```
$searchUrl = $packageRepo.Trim('/')#($packageRepo.Trim('/'), 'Packages()?$filter=(Id%20eq%20%27chocolatey%27)%20and%20IsLatestVersion') -join '/'
```

6. Run the chocoofflline ps1 script.

*Debug:*
If you have an error here:
`Download-Package $searchUrl $localChocolateyPackageFilePath`

7. Manually download the file instead and comment out Download-Package line, so do

`cp d:/chocoOfflineRepository/chocolatey.0.10.15.nupkg C:\ProgramData\choco-cache\chocolatey.nupkg`

8. Then run this line or entire ps1 script again

```
  Install-ChocolateyFromPackage $localChocolateyPackageFilePath
```

Note like @ferventcoder pointed out, it's not deterministic, some package may not work because of internal dependencies or proxy limitation. In my case I couldn't use remote community library because of corporate proxy, so I'm using this until I figure out a better solution. =)